# Replace text in UITextView with linkable text - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have dynamic text that contains user name as place holder, I want to replace the place holder of user name with actual user name but I want this name to be linkable,in other words when I click on the user name it should perform a certain selector which redirects to the profile page. Is this doable?

This is my code:

```
NSString *originalText = @"go to :user profile or go to :place";
NSString *userText = @"Sawsan";
NSString *placeText = @"SomePlace";

originalText = [originalText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":user"
                                                             withString:userText];
originalText = [originalText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":place"
                                                             withString:placeText];
self.mainLabel.text = originalText;

/*
 * Result is: "go to Sawsan profile or go to SomePlace"
 */
```

Can I replace `:user` and `:place` with Sawsan and SomePlace that can perform different `selector` when the user click on any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
self.mainLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pushAction)];
[self.mainLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

PushAction:

```
-(void)pushAction
{
    NSLog(@"mainLabel tapped");
}
```

Additionally I would do it like this with the user:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"go to %@ profile", userText];
```

Comment: What if I have more than one dynamic text like :user and :place? I want each of them perform different selector

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that :[